# "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long" with astropy.table

Tags: python, astropy

I want to read a simple table, using astropy.table. The first element of the line is a large integer. It fails, with error message: "OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long". How can I avoid this?

Details:

The table is in test.cat. It is very simple, one line:
81421100001  2  1  1  37.5991  1.0213  785.364  539.291

Here is the code I use:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.table import Table

catalog_filename = 'test.cat'

t = Table.read(catalog_filename, format='ascii')
```

I receive the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "catread.py", line 15, in <module>
    t = Table.read(catalog_filename, format='ascii')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/table/table.py", line 2561, in read
    return io_registry.read(cls, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/registry.py", line 319, in read
    table = reader(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/connect.py", line 18, in read_asciitable
    return read(filename, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/ui.py", line 154, in read
    dat = _guess(table, new_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/ui.py", line 196, in _guess
    dat = reader.read(table)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/core.py", line 872, in read
    table = self.outputter(cols, self.meta)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/core.py", line 670, in __call__
    self._convert_vals(cols)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/core.py", line 652, in _convert_vals
    col.data = converter_func(col.str_vals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/astropy/io/ascii/core.py", line 611, in converter
    return numpy.array(vals, numpy_type)
OverflowError: Python int too large to convert to C long
```

Comment: 32-bit, I think. At least, typing platform.architecture() gives me ('32bit', 'ELF').

Comment: That was intended as a vague suggestion, not a question ;)

Comment: This is an issue with 64-bit Python too, except that the integer at which this becomes a problem is larger. I have opened https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/2234.

Comment: Thanks a lot for working on this! When should I expect the next stable version with this issue corrected?

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, this is now an astropy issue (https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/2234) and there is a proposed fix which will automatically fall back to string in case of an overflow.  In the meantime you can instruct the `ascii.read` function to use a specific numpy dtype for converting the column from a text string to the final table column.  Use the `converters` keyword arg like below.

```
>>> ascii.read(['8142110000100000000 1 2 3'], 
               converters={'col1': [ascii.convert_numpy(np.int64)]})
<Table rows=1 names=('col1','col2','col3','col4')>
array([(8142110000100000000, 1, 2, 3)], 
    dtype=[('col1', '<i8'), ('col2', '<i8'), ('col3', '<i8'), ('col4', '<i8')])

>>> ascii.read(['8142110000100000000 1 2 3'], 
                converters={'col1': [ascii.convert_numpy(np.float)]})
<Table rows=1 names=('col1','col2','col3','col4')>
array([(8.1421100001e+18, 1, 2, 3)], 
  dtype=[('col1', '<f8'), ('col2', '<i8'), ('col3', '<i8'), ('col4', '<i8')])
```

Comment: Without knowing the nature of the data that OP is working with, I would strongly recommend against converting to `float`. It completely changes the numerical complexion of the data and any ensuing calculations. Yes, `int64` breaks ungracefully (same as OP's original problem), but until that breaking point, you still get clean integer math, and `int64` has greater integer precision than `float`.

Comment: Agree with John Y above.  The fix in https://github.com/astropy/astropy/issues/2234 (now merged) was changed to fall back to string and emit a warning in the case of an overflow.  This is always safe from the perspective of not losing information, and the user can handle the string array as needed.